# MongoDB conditional relation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB 4.2.2,

I have 2 collections Polls and Votes, I need to grab field `voter_selection` from "Votes" collection and add it to Polls but only if certain conditions match `poll_id` & `voter_id`

User:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f867e0d126ddbde24d6ee73"),
"name" : "Jaskson"
"age" : "24"
}
```

Polls:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f87d988ddae726a3dbe5459"),
"name" : "RedVsWhite"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f51408ffc1d0437fa31d6f7"),
"name" : "ApplesVsOrange",
"total_votes" : "0",
}
```

Votes:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f864addddae726a3dbe53de"),
"voter_id" : ObjectId("5f867e0d126ddbde24d6ee73"), //this is the id of the person
"poll_id" : ObjectId("5f87d988ddae726a3dbe5459"), //this is the poll id
"voter_selection" : "red"
}
```

I need this Result:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f87d988ddae726a3dbe5459"),
"name" : "RedVsWhite",
"total_votes" : "0",
"voter_selection" : red // show this if it finds votes with this _id and also if user_id match & voter_id
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f51408ffc1d0437fa31d6f7"),
"name" : "ApplesVsOrange",
"total_votes" : "0"
/// dont show voter_selection if nothing match with voter_id and poll_id
}
```

This query works, but the problem is that if nothing match it wont show the polls rows, and what I need is to get all polls even if there is no match but if there is a match add the field `voter_selection` to the row

```
db.getCollection("Polls").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "localField": "_id",
                "from": "VotesRecords",
                "foreignField": "poll_id",
                "as": "VotesRecords"
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$VotesRecords",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "VotesRecords.voter_id": ObjectId("5f867e0d126ddbde24d6ee73")
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "name": "$name",
                "voter_selection": "$VotesRecords.voter_selection"
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: The aggregation looks right. You are just missing "total_votes": "$total_votes" in your $project stage.

Comment: $total_Votes is just an illustration for Polls collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by null and make a array of all elements of root
- `$lookup` to join collection with `VotesRecords` and get user details
- `$unwind` deconstruct `VotesRecords` array
- `$project` iterate loop through `$map` on `root` array and check condition if match `poll_id` then return `voter_selection` otherwise nothing using
- `$unwind` deconstruct root array
- `$replaceWith` to replace `root` object in root

```
db.getCollection("Polls").aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "VotesRecords",
      as: "VotesRecords",
      pipeline: [{ $match: { voter_id: ObjectId("5f867e0d126ddbde24d6ee73") } }]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$VotesRecords",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      root: {
        $map: {
          input: "$root",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$VotesRecords.poll_id"] },
                  { voter_selection: "$VotesRecords.voter_selection" },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0keG7YhVANp)

---

Second approach, you can add below changes after your pipelines,

- `$project` to show `voter_selection` if `voter_id` match otherwise `$$REMOVE`
- `$group` by `_id` and get unique object out of many using `$mergeObjects`
- `$replaceWith` to replace root object

```
  // <= skipping your pipelines here
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": "$name",
      "total_votes": 1,
      "voter_selection": {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$VotesRecords.voter_id", ObjectId("5f867e0d126ddbde24d6ee73")] },
          "$VotesRecords.voter_selection",
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      root: { $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ks1d8BXpcGN)